# Simple Ruby server setup using Thin as a simple rhtml server (like Webrick)

Tags: ruby, server, rack, thin, webrick

my simple Webrick server serves up static html and rhtml embedded ruby files.  How would I achieve the same with a multithreaded or multiprocess Ruby server like Thin?

Webrick setup:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# simple_servlet_server.rb
require 'webrick'
include WEBrick
s = HTTPServer.new(:Port => 8000)

# Add a mime type for *.rhtml files
HTTPUtils::DefaultMimeTypes.store('rhtml', 'text/html')

s.mount('/', HTTPServlet::FileHandler, './public_html')

['TERM', 'INT'].each do |signal|
 trap(signal){ s.shutdown }
end

s.start
```

I have installed Thin and Rack, my config.ru reads HTML but wont render rhtml docs?:

```
  use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    },
    File.open('./public_html', File::RDONLY)
  ]

  HTTPUtils::DefaultMimeTypes.store('rhtml', 'text/html')      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;** - Dynamic ruby content (i.e., `.rhtml` files) needs to be rendered by a template engine; The built-in engine used by WebRick is Ruby's `ERB` engine; Render dynamic files before sending the Rack response.

---

1. I would recommend that you separate the static files from the dynamic files.

   This would allow you to optimize the static file service using either the reverse proxy (i.e., nginx) or a static file enabled Ruby server (i.e., iodine).

   A common approach is to:

   - Place static files under `./public`.
   - Place dynamic files under `./app/views`.
2. Your Rack application will need to process the dynamic files using the appropriate template engine processor.

   For your `.rhtml` files I would **assume** that this would be the built-in `ERB` template engine (there's a nice post about it [here](https://blog.revathskumar.com/2014/10/ruby-rendering-erb-template.html)).

Assuming you placed your dynamic files and static files as mentioned, you might start up with a `config.ru` file that looks like this:

```
require 'erb'
require 'pathname'

ROOT ||= Pathname.new(File.dirname(__FILE__)).expand_path

module APP
  VIEWS = ROOT.join('app', 'views')
  def self.call(env)
    # prevent folder trasversal (security) and extract file name
    return [403, {}, ["Not Allowed!"]] if env['PATH_INFO'].index("..") || env['PATH_INFO'].index("//")
    filename = VIEWS.join(env['PATH_INFO'][1..-1])
    # make sure file exists
    return [404, {}, ["Not Found"]] unless File.exists?(filename)
    # process dynamic content
    template = IO.binread filename
    data = ERB.new(template).result(binding)
    return [200, {}, [data]]
  end
end

run APP
```

Next you can run the application with iodine, which will handle the static file service part (in this example, a single threaded worker per core):

```
iodine -w -1 -t 1 -www public
```

Of course, you can use the `Rack::Static` middleware, but it should prove to be significantly slower (bench mark it yourself or test it against Thin)...

...I'm iodine's author, so I might be biased.

#### EDIT

P.S. (side note about security and performance)

I would reconsider the template engine.

ERB is fast and effective, however, it also allows code to be executed within the template.

This could result in difficult project maintenance as code leaks into the template, making the code less readable and harder to maintain.

I would consider switching to Mustache templates, which prevent code from running within the template.

Changing the template engine could also improve performance. Consider the following benchmark, using [iodine flavored mustache templates](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/boazsegev/iodine/master/Iodine/Mustache) (which offer aggressive HTML escaping):

```
require 'iodine'
require 'erb'
require 'benchmark'

module Base
  ERB_ENG = ERB.new("<%= data %> <%= Time.now %>")
  MUS_ENG = Iodine::Mustache.new(nil, "{{ data }} {{ date }}")
  def self.render_erb(data)
    ERB_ENG.result(binding)
  end
  def self.render_mus(data)
    h = {data: data, date: Time.now.to_s }
    MUS_ENG.render(h)
  end
end

puts "#{Base.render_mus("hello")} == #{Base.render_erb("hello")} : #{(Base.render_mus("hello") == Base.render_erb("hello"))}"

TIMES = 100_000
Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report("Ruby ERB") { TIMES.times { Base.render_erb("hello") } }
  bm.report("Iodine  ") { TIMES.times { Base.render_mus("hello") } }
end
```

The results, on my machine, were (lower is better):

```
            user     system      total        real
Ruby ERB  1.701363   0.006301   1.707664 (  1.709132)
Iodine    0.256918   0.000750   0.257668 (  0.258190)
```

Again, since I'm iodine's author, I'm biased. Play around and find what's best for you.